# Models are available as .ckpt and .safetensors - which should I use?

Tags: untagged

I've noticed that some locally-runnable models are available as `.ckpt` files, others as `.safetensors` files, and some - like [Stable Diffusion 1.5](https://huggingface.co/runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5/tree/main) - are available as both.

What's the difference between these two formats, and should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Use `.safetensors` where available. Don't load untrusted `.ckpt` files.**

---

`.ckpt` (sometimes instead having extension `.pt` or `.pth`) is PyTorch's model save format, based on `pickle` for storing arbitrary Python objects. However, this format was not designed for safety and can execute arbitrary code:

> [**Warning**: The `pickle` module is **not secure**. Only unpickle data you trust.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)
> [It is possible to construct malicious pickle data which will **execute arbitrary code during unpickling**. Never unpickle data that could have come from an untrusted source, or that could have been tampered with.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Some sites and frontends may have partial mitigations in place, such as Huggingface which scans `pickle` files and provides a list of imports they make, highlighting potentially dangerous ones:

[image: Huggingface detected pickles imports]

`.safetensors` is a newer format [developed by Huggingface](https://github.com/huggingface/safetensors) to address that issue, and also has other advantages such as being zero-copy (reading the file doesn't require more memory than the original file).